# Is it true that English has "evolved" to say that "Jim and me" instead of "Jim and I" is correct?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, grammatical-case

My English teacher was saying that English has "evolved" so that saying "Jim and me" or "me and Jim" is acceptable to use in instances like "Me and Jim are going to the bathroom". Here is what I found on http://www.businessinsider.com.au/i-or-me-grammar-mistake-2014-12?r=US&IR=T

> Consider these two sentences:
>
> > He’s taking Jane and me to the park.
> >
> > He’s taking Jane and I to the park.
>
> Which is correct?
>
> > If you said the first, you’re right:
> >
> > He’s taking Jane and me to the park.
>
> It’s right because “Jane and me” are the objects of the sentence (the
>   things being taken) while “he” is the subject (the thing that is
>   taking). After all, “me” is the objective form of the first person
>   pronoun while “I” is the subjective form.

This confuses me because I was always taught that if you are mentioning another person, you always say "that person and I". Could someone help me, thanks. Please upvote if you have the same question :)

Comment: Common usage and what is traditionally grammatically "correct" are often two different things.  What you were taught applies if "that person and I" are the subject: "Jim and I are going to the movies".  But if they are the object it's different: "Give Al Gore and me a chance". (Instead of "Give Al Gore and I a chance" which got President Clinton in trouble with the grammar police.)

Comment: Methinks you might consider another English teacher. Using *me* (or *myself*) as part of the subject of a verb - or *I* as part of the object is simply wrong. It's a common mistake to use *that person and I* as an object because it sounds classier.

Comment: I would disagree with your English teacher.

Comment: "He's taking Jane and I to the park" has *never* been correct because "Jane and I" are the object! That sentence is [hypercorrection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercorrection#Personal_pronouns). (But arguably it has now become grammatical. Anyone arguing that it is now grammatical must also accept that "you and me" is a grammatical subject ;))

Comment: @curiousdannii do you use HTML to create the table? How do you do it???

Comment: @LouieBnouie http://english.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: To train my son out of saying "Me and XX played such-and-so," I ask, "Who is Me-am (rhymes with Liam)?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

English is always evolving, so common usage can eventually be accepted as correct.
I believe that the context makes the difference. If you would say "I am going to the park" you should also say "Jane and I are going to the park".

Similarly, if "Will you come to the park with me?" is correct, then 
"Will you come to the park with Jane and me?" is also correct.

Comment: Why does it have to be that way? There isn't any overwhelming reason why we have to use the same forms of the pronoun in coordinate structures as in isolated noun phrases. In French, you say "**je** vais" = "I go" but "Jeanne et **moi** allons" = "Jane and I go".